# jQuery- Logo from header goes in sticky navbar when scrolling down

Tags: jquery, navbar, sticky

How can you make a smaller img of your logo drop in the sticky nav when scrolling down.

I'm looking for something exactly like in this webpage http://bungobox.com/.

I got the part on how to make it fixed, but other than that i can't seem to find a way.

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make basic example for you,

check it : http://jsfiddle.net/mehmetakifalp/pt4vB/

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".headLogo").css("height","60px");
    $(".headLogo").css("background","#ff0000");
    $(".headLogo").css("position","fixed");
});
```

Logic like this :

- When the scroll down on window, find class and edit some Css property -

If you can calculate scroll position, u can manage css. e.g when the scroll position == 0, remove old css properties.

furthermore, check this page; 
1- [jQuery - Sticky header that shrinks when scrolling down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442016/jquery-sticky-header-that-shrinks-when-scrolling-down)
2- http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/sticky-scroll
3- http://jsfiddle.net/HbVte/1/embedded/result/

Your google dork : "**sticky header**"