# Padding animate latency

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

I'm trying to create fixed-top menu, and resize them (by changing padding top&bottom) when window scrolled down > 300px for example.
If i try that after 300px from top, set css style like `$('nav').css('padding', '30px 0 30px 0');` all work fine, but if i try to do this with animation, i get huge latency between events.

There is example:
Without animate - http://jsfiddle.net/g3xLgLeb/1/  (all work fine)

With animate - http://jsfiddle.net/g3xLgLeb/  (huge latency)

Comment: every time you scroll you call an animation: you should check before if `$nav.is(':animated');` before starting a new animation

Comment: Hope this post helps you to achieve your [goal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442016/jquery-sticky-header-that-shrinks-when-scrolling-down)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to use CSS transition rather than jQuery animation for this.

Here's how you can do it.

Add the following css to your existing css file:

```
.nav.custom{
  padding-top:5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  -webkit-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: all ease 0.5s;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
}
```

Use the following as your script:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        var $nav = $('.nav');
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 350) {
                $nav.addClass('custom');
            } else {
                $nav.removeClass('custom');
            }
        });
    });
```

**NOTE:** The css transitions may not work in some older browsers. Here's a list showing the [cross browser compatibility](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp).

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: @Benjamin, I don't think it will work that way. Because `toggleClass` will be then called only if `scrollTop() > 350`. So when will it add the class and when will it remove?

Comment: @kxc It helps but beware you will get cross browser compatibility issues.

Comment: @kxc check this [link](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions) for more details