# Why is not my div shrinking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I could not comment on [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442016/jquery-sticky-header-that-shrinks-when-scrolling-down), that's why I posted a similar question.(*I must have at least 50 reputation for that*)
I wanted to know why it is not shrinking, I  understood the code exactly as [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442016/jquery-sticky-header-that-shrinks-when-scrolling-down) 1st answer was and then tried to code exactly same so that the results be same but nothing happened after scrolling my `div`'s size remained same

### Here's my entire code:

```
    <html>
  <div id="header_nav"></div>
  <div class="container">
    ....
  </div>
  </html>
  <style>
     .container{padding-top:100px;}
  body {
    height: 500px;s
    width: 100%;s
    background-color: #00000;
  }

  #header_nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #666;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  </style>
  <script>
  $(function(){
    $('#header_nav').data('size', 'big');
  });

  $(window).scroll(function(){
      if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
        if ($('#header_nav').data('size') === ('big')) {
          $('##header_nav').data('size','small');
          $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
            height: '40px'
          }, 600);
        }
      }
      else{
        if ('#header_nav'.data('size') === ('small')) {
          $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
          $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
            height: '100px'
          }, 600)
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Can you create an example in codepen.io? The example does not provide us with sufficient data to figure out what the problem might be.

Comment: $('header_nav') => $('#header_nav')

Comment: Show the arrangement of your code resource so that exact problem could be sorted out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated!!!**

Remove **#** from this line because there are one extra # `$('#header_nav').data('size','small');`

And no need to add this line in `else` section, remove this line below

```
if('#header_nav').data('size') === ('small')) {      $('#header_nav').data('size','big');}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#header_nav').data('size', 'big');
 
 $(window).scroll(function(){
      if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
        if ($('#header_nav').data('size') === ('big')) {
          $('#header_nav').data('size','small');
          $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
            height: '40px'
          }, 600);
        }
      }
      else{
       // Just add animate function only without any condition
        $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
            height: '100px'
          }, 600);
      }
  });
})
```

```css
.container{padding-top:100px;}
  body {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00000;
  }

  #header_nav {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #666;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <div id="header_nav"></div>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
  </html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much it does work now but.. when I scroll up again it remains shrinked.

Comment: Anytime :)
Could you please explain why you giving condition like this in else `$('#header_nav').data('size') === ('small'))` There is no need to add this, now check the updated snippet

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add `#` before id.
Replace this part of your code with this:

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
      if ($(document).scrollTop() > 0) {
        if ($('#header_nav').data('size') === ('big')) {
          $('#header_nav').data('size','small');
          $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
            height: '40px'
          }, 600);
        }
      }
      else{
        if ('#header_nav'.data('size') === ('small')) {
          $('#header_nav').data('size','big');
          $('#header_nav').stop().animate({
            height: '100px'
          }, 600)
        }
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is here:

```
if ($('#header_nav').data('size') === ('big')) {
    $('header_nav').data('size','small');
    $('header_nav').stop().animate({
        height: '40px'
    }, 600);
}
```

here `$('header_nav').data('size','small');` doesn't have `#` in the selector.

So change it to:

```
$('#header_nav').data('size','small');
```

and try again.

Comment: the results are still same ,`div` is not shrinking after scrolling down.

Comment: If any other solution please tell.

Comment: Still the issue is there ?

Comment: Yes it is still same.