# Responsive scroll header not resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been trying to get a fixed header to resize when page is scrolled but having difficulty getting the header to resize when the scrolling occurs.

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  navbarScroll();
});

function navbarScroll() {
  var y = window.scrollY;
  if (y > 10) {
    $('.Header').addClass('small');
  } else if (y < 10) {
    $('.Header').removeClass('small');
  }
}
```

```css
.Header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #d8341f;
}

.Header--top {
  display: block;
  background: #fafafa;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: auto;
}

.tweak-site-width-option-full-background .Header-inner {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.Header .Header--top {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: .3s;
  // header shrinks when .small added to .Header
  &.small {
    height: 70px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(black, .2);
    // when Header.small also change page offset
    &~.offset {
      padding-top: 140px;
    }
    // when Header.small change logo pad & font size
    .header_logo {
      padding-top: 20px;
      font-size: 20px;
      text-shadow: none;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="Header Header--top">
  <div class="Header-inner Header-inner--top" data-nc-group="top">
    <div data-nc-container="top-left">
      <a href="/" class="Header-branding" data-nc-element="branding" data-content-field="site-title">
        <img src="//static1.squarespace.com/static/5aa819f2aa49a1758e33b803/t/5aa85d9cec212dd645589158/1524261284838/?format=1500w" alt="Red Corp USA" class="Header-branding-logo">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div data-nc-container="top-center"></div>
    <div data-nc-container="top-right">
      <nav class="Header-nav Header-nav--primary" data-nc-element="primary-nav" data-content-field="navigation">
        <div class="Header-nav-inner">
          <a href="/about/" class="Header-nav-item" data-test="template-nav">About</a><a href="/commercial/" class="Header-nav-item" data-test="template-nav">Commercial</a><a href="/residential/" class="Header-nav-item" data-test="template-nav">Residential</a>
          <a href="/hospitality/" class="Header-nav-item" data-test="template-nav">Hospitality</a><a href="/projects/" class="Header-nav-item" data-test="template-nav">Projects</a><a href="/contact/" class="Header-nav-item" data-test="template-nav">Contact</a>
          <a
            href="tel:+1.301.785.2400" target="_blank" class="Header-nav-item">Call Now</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

An example of what I am looking to get is at https://studio10interiordesign.com and my current site is located at https://www.redcorpusa.com if it helps any.

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16442016/jquery-sticky-header-that-shrinks-when-scrolling-down

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript is fine, although you don't need the anonymous function.

The issue is your CSS. Firstly the nested `&.[class]` is LESS syntax, so I hope you are transpiling that. Secondly, you have `.Header .Header--top` when you probably mean `.Header.Header--top` (since in your HTML, these classes are on the same element, not nested within each other)

Here is a working example with minimal changes to your code and some lorem ipsum to have a scrollbar, although, it needs better styling ^^

```js
function navbarScroll() {
  var y = window.scrollY;

  if (y > 10) {
    $('.Header').addClass('small');
  } else if (y < 10) {
    $('.Header').removeClass('small');
  }
}

$(document).scroll(navbarScroll);
```

```css
.Header {
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  border-bottom: solid 2px #d8341f;
}

.Header--top {
  display: block;
  background: #fafafa;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: auto;
}

.tweak-site-width-option-full-background .Header-inner {
  max-width: 1140px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.Header.Header--top {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: .3s;
}

.Header.Header--top.small {
  height: 70px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(black, .2);
}

.Header.Header--top.small img {
 height: 80px;
}

.offset {
  padding-top: 140px;
}

.header_logo {
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="Header Header--top">
  <div class="Header-inner Header-inner--top" data-nc-group="top">
    <div data-nc-container="top-left">
      <a href="/" class="Header-branding" data-nc-element="branding" data-content-field="site-title">
        <img src="//static1.squarespace.com/static/5aa819f2aa49a1758e33b803/t/5aa85d9cec212dd645589158/1524261284838/?format=1500w" alt="Red Corp USA" class="Header-branding-logo">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div data-nc-container="top-center"></div>
    <div data-nc-container="top-right">
      <nav class="Header-nav Header-nav--primary" data-nc-element="primary-nav" data-content-field="navigation">
        <div class="Header-nav-inner">
          <a href="/about/" class="Header-nav-item" data-test="template-nav">About</a><a href="/commercial/" class="Header-nav-item" data-test="template-nav">Commercial</a><a href="/residential/" class="Header-nav-item" data-test="template-nav">Residential</a>
          <a href="/hospitality/" class="Header-nav-item" data-test="template-nav">Hospitality</a><a href="/projects/" class="Header-nav-item" data-test="template-nav">Projects</a><a href="/contact/" class="Header-nav-item" data-test="template-nav">Contact</a>
          <a href="tel:+1.301.785.2400" target="_blank" class="Header-nav-item">Call Now</a>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."
Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC "Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto
beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet,
consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi
consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?" 1914 translation by H. Rackham "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken
idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids
pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because
it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has
any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?" Section 1.10.33 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC "At vero
eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollitia animi,
id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum facilis est et expedita distinctio. Nam libero tempore, cum soluta nobis est eligendi optio cumque nihil impedit quo minus id quod maxime placeat facere possimus, omnis voluptas assumenda est, omnis
dolor repellendus. Temporibus autem quibusdam et aut officiis debitis aut rerum necessitatibus saepe eveniet ut et voluptates repudiandae sint et molestiae non recusandae. Itaque earum rerum hic tenetur a sapiente delectus, ut aut reiciendis voluptatibus
maiores alias consequatur aut perferendis doloribus asperiores repellat." 1914 translation by H. Rackham "On the other hand, we denounce with righteous indignation and dislike men who are so beguiled and demoralized by the charms of pleasure of the moment,
so blinded by desire, that they cannot foresee the pain and trouble that are bound to ensue; and equal blame belongs to those who fail in their duty through weakness of will, which is the same as saying through shrinking from toil and pain. These cases
are perfectly simple and easy to distinguish. In a free hour, when our power of choice is untrammelled and when nothing prevents our being able to do what we like best, every pleasure is to be welcomed and every pain avoided. But in certain circumstances
and owing to the claims of duty or the obligations of business it will frequently occur that pleasures have to be repudiated and annoyances accepted. The wise man therefore always holds in these matters to this principle of selection: he rejects pleasures
to secure other greater pleasures, or else he endures pains to avoid worse pains."
```

Comment: Maybe something that might good to add  into the `if` conditions... Check if the element has the `class` before trying to add/remove it each time the scroll function executes. **For Example:** `if((y>10)&&(!$(".Header").hasClass("small")))` [**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/g9kmtoLb/)

Comment: @NewToJS good point, I didn't want to change the JS much since that wasn't the issue with the code. I would also cache the `.Header` element.

Comment: It seems to be getting there although question on the content and logo inside the header. Logo and content don't seem to be resizing with the responsiveness of the header. Is this something that would be accomplished through css and using the class `.small` or is this also accomplished through JS? @NewToJS Current state is viewable at [http://redcorpusa.com]

Comment: @jamiechalski just reduce the size of the image when `.Header.small`. I've updated my example to do this in a basic way. Since the CSS (LESS?) you posted isn't the full version of your site's stylesheet, the above is just a sample of the technique you can use. You will have to tweak your styles to make them responsive. The example site you posted resizes the inner content to be a percentage `height` of the parent header, so that's also an option.

Answer (score 0):

Change the style file

```
.Header .Header--top {
...
}
```

to: ( without space)

```
.Header.Header--top {}
```